# Dealing with Windows line-endings in Python

Tags: python, file

I've got a 700MB XML file coming from a Windows provider.

As one might expect, the line endings are '\r\n' (or ^M in vi).  What is the most efficient way to deal with this situation aside from getting the supplier to send over '\n' :-)

1. Use [os.linesep](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.linesep)
2. Use [rstrip()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) (requiring opening the file ... which seems crazy)
3. Using [Universal newline support](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) is not standard on my Mac Snow Leopard - so isn't an option.

I'm open to anything that requires Python 2.6+ but it needs to work on Snow Leopard and Ubuntu 9.10 with minimal external requirements.  I don't mind a small performance penalty but I am looking for the standard best way to deal with this.

----edit----

The line endings are in the middle of the tag descriptors, otherwise they wouldn't be such a problem.  I know this is bad form and that they shouldn't be sending this to me, but this is how I have the file and the vendor is mostly incompetent.

Comment: So how do you know if the whitespace is required or not?  You surely can't just go and remove all of the whitespace.  E.g. how would you collapse `<xxx yyy zzz>` given this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allegedly: """This guy has \r\n right in the middle of tag descriptors like so: `<ParentRedirec tSequenceID>`""".

I see no `\r\n` here. Perhaps you mean repr(xml) contains things like

```
"<ParentRedirec\r\ntSequenceID>"
```

If not, try to say *precisely* what you mean, with repr-fashion *examples*.

The following should work:

```
>>> import re
>>> guff = """<atag>\r\n<bt\r\nag c="2">"""
>>> re.sub(r"(<[^>]*)\r\n([^>]*>)", r"\1\2", guff)
'<atag>\r\n<btag c="2">'
>>>
```

If there is more than one line break in a tag e.g. `<foo\r\nbar\r\nzot>` this will fix only the first. Alternatives (1) loop until the guff stops shrinking (2) write a smarter regexp yourself :-)

Comment: You are correct, the comment system stripped out the newlines, the tags are like:

    "<ParentRedirec\r\ntSequenceID>"

Answer (score 6):

Why are the DOS line-endings a problem? Most things can deal with them just fine, including XML parsers. If you really want to get rid of them, open the file in `universal line-endings` mode:

```
open(filename, 'rU')
```

Python will convert all line-endings to UNIX line-endings for you. If you really can't use that (which I find a little surprising), there's no way to get Python to do the work for you. You will have to open the file regardless, though, so your objection to #2 seems a little odd.

Comment: huh, just (re-)read the docs- never know that U was "required" to turn on universal newline support...  Most of my work is on Windows and unix newlines are (thankfully) handled gracefully...

Comment: The text-mode reading on Windows, where the MS C runtime will convert line-endings for you, is not the same as Python's universal line-endings support. Universal line-endings are the same on all operating systems. The Windows text-mode thing is specific to Windows (and also affects other things, like the EOF character causing a premature EOF.)

Comment: Universal new lines aren't available for my system.

Answer (score 2):

Are you opening the file in text mode or binary mode?  I'm pretty sure I've counted on universal newlines on my Leopard install, but maybe I got an updated Python from somewhere too...

Anyway- I've seen this sort of thing biting many programmers in the bum, because they just reach for the 'b' key.  Use a 't' if you're opening text files known to be created on your platform, 'U' instead of 't' if you need universal newlines.

```
with file(filename, 'rt') as f:
   content = f.read()
```

**Edit:** The comments note that 'rt' is the default.  Fair point, but Python style tends to prefer explicit over implicit, so I'm going with that.

Comment: Closest to an ok answer.  I need a better file I now realize.

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of `'t'` not being the default mode everywhere. Can you elaborate on this? Is `'rt'` really different from `'r'`? Is the default really `'b'`, or is there a third mode?

Comment: I looked at the docs after posting.  I suspect that 't' is default based on what I saw, but I feel that explicit is better than implicit.  :)  Anyway- I've also seen a lot of people just throw a 'b' in there by default, even when dealing with text files.  The mind boggles, but it's something that happens, so I asked.  ;)

Comment: Thomas is being too gentle. 'rt' is the same as 't'.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: s/probably a bit wrong/definitely wrong/ ... do yourself a favour and delete your answer.

Comment: Would've if it weren't accepted and undeletable.  Edited instead.  I similarly put parentheses around all but the most trivial of expressions to make order of operation unambiguous to the casual reader.  We could get into a philosophical discussion, were this the appropriate forum.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with this file?  Whitespace between tags is usually ignored in XML, so the only place where line endings matter tags' content.

Comment: This guy has \r\n right in the middle of tag descriptors like so:

    <ParentRedirec
    
    tSequenceID>

I would much prefer they fix it on their end but I'm kind of in a rush and just want to strip this stuff.

Comment: If that's the case it's broken in any case -- a \n instead of \r\n wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I was thinking of stripping all newlines of any kind but now I realize that it won't work because some of the blocks have valid newlines that are part of the actual data.