# strange ubuntu file format issue

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have encountered a very strange problem with 'txt' file in ubuntu, I have a txt file that when reads from windows with python command `open('file.txt','r').readlines()`, it gives `\n` of each end of line, but when I read it on ubuntu machines with the same `open('file.txt','r').readlines()`, it gives `\r\n` endings, what's the problem?(I expected the `\n` ending)

==EDIT==

Just to make it clear, because most people link some question like 'what is \r and what is \n'. That's not the problem here.

The problem is as follows:

- You have a file, let's say file.txt
- Read the file (using Python) on windows and it produces `\n` line endings
- Read (supposedly) the same file (using Python) on linux and it produces `\r\n` line endings
- Isn't it counter-intuitive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with Windows line-endings in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717086/dealing-with-windows-line-endings-in-python)

Comment: Text files created on DOS/Windows machines have different line endings than files created on Unix/Linux. DOS uses carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n").  This is answered plenty of times already in the forum.

Comment: @SebastianWozny I doubt that's a duplicate, because question tells us that it's the opposite situation from what we would expect.

Comment: Do you use any ftp client?

Comment: To understand that you need to go through this link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r>

Comment: @RajshekharHoratti again I recommend to read the question with understanding

Comment: The Python runtime on windows will just take care of it and represent it correctly as `\n` wihle the ubuntu runtime won't.

Comment: You can use open().read().splitlines() instead to avoid dealing with different line endings

Comment: In Python 2, if you want Linux to automatically handle reading Windows CRLF newlines you need to explicitly request universal newlines in the  `open` mode arg, as mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), and your Python has to be built with universal newlines support (it usually is).